# How to get VBAs ByRef return from Python over COM

Tags: python, excel, vba, byref

(I'm no good in English sorry...)

I want to get value in VBA using ByRef parameter from Python. Because I need to return several values from VBA.

example.

```
' VBA
Sub GetValue(ByRef v As Variant)
    v = "some cell value"
End Sub 

#Python
#app is Excel.Application
v = ''
app.Run('GetValue', v)
Print(v)
```

I tried using xlwings and win32com but v comes initial value ''.

Similar code by PowerShell was succeeded. I have no idea to solve. Someone teach me please.

Thanks.

Comment: `GetValue` could be a function returning an array of values.

Comment: I have to call existing macro so I cannot change signature...

Comment: So you can't touch the VBA in that workbook?

Comment: You could open *another* workbook which contains a Run'able Function which calls `GetValue` in the first workbook, gets the ByRef result, then returns it to your Python code.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I try it. Making another workbook for adapter.